# Windows firewall IP scope is not applied

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, ip-address

I have a port opened that I want to have available by whitelisted IP (or IP blocks) only, yet when I test it from a connection outside the whitelist, the connection is still accepted.

[image]

The Firewall policy for the network profile is set to **Block (default)**

What setting am I missing?

**EDIT**: Solved.  A duplicate rule was preventing this rule from functioning as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a duplicate rule.